# Is it possible to use a Picklist from a Dialogbox?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I've tried it but when the Picklist opens, the Dialogbox form that opened it closes.

I'm opening the Dialogbox using the Queryopendocument event of a view.

```
Sub Queryopendocument(Source As Notesuiview, Continue As Variant)
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Set doc = Source.Documents.GetFirstDocument()
If not doc is Nothing then
  Call ws.Dialogbox("Item", True, True, True, False, False, False, "My Item", doc, True, True, True)
End If
'Set Continue to false to prohibit opening of the document
Continue = False
End Sub
```

The dialogbox opens fine and displays the data.

Then, on the dialogbox form there is a button to open a Picklist so I can pick a different item. I want my selection to populate the ItemName field on the dialogbox.

Here's the code for the button.

```
sContent:=@PickList( [Custom]:[Single] ; "" ; "ProductLookup" ; "Product Selector" ; "Select a product from the list"; 4);
@SetField("ItemName";"sContent")
```

The problem is, when I click the picklist button on the dialogbox and the picklist pops open, the underlying dialogbox closes.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just not possible? I thought I had it working for a bit but I can't get it to work now.

Comment: It's been ages, but my recollection is that it's not possible.

Comment: @jeff-shall Wat version of Notes (& FP) are you using?
I did a small test on v9.01 FP7 and it seems to work.

Comment: I'm using 9.01 fp3